# Internal HDD not being detected by my PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a Seagate internal hdd that recently stopped being detected by my pc (running on windows 7). It was detected by the seatools for windows and, oddly enough, even passed a SMART test. Failed short and long generic tests and, when I checked the drive info, it says it's 4gb with 3.67gb used. The hdd is actually 2tb.

I changed ports on the mother board and even swapped cables, but nothing changed. But let me back up a bit: it all started when my computer wasn't booting, more precisely, it wasn't going past the MB loading screen. I managed to boot it and in disk management, the hdd wasn't showing, but there was an unassigned drive of 128gb (that confused me because that's the same capacity of my ssd that I never managed to get going lol). I removed the ssd, and that remained the same. After trying swapping cables and ports again, I decided to remove the seagate hdd. After that my pc started to boot normally (every time I had to turn it on while trying to troubleshoot, I had to boot windows via Bios) and the unassigned disk of 128gb also disappeared (it was still showing after I removed the ssd).

Now, I'm going to buy a sata/usb adapter to try my hdd in another computer and eventually even open it if I have to. But before I do that I'd like to know what you guys think about all of this. Is the hdd dead? What could be the source of the failure? There was something I should have tried or done differently? Is there still hope?!

So, going over again: it wasn't the cables; it passed a SMART test, failed both short and long generic, the hdd info via seatools said it had 4gb capacity and disk management was detecting a 128gb disk that wasn't my ssd. Also, I couldn't tell if it was doing any sound as it was near my working WD internal hdd.

Sorry if this was a bit convoluted. It's my first question here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best guess, it was a [hybrid drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive) [SSHD] which was either never correctly recognised or set up. I'd guess at least the NAND part is now dead… as will be the HD part of it if you open it up! Test on an external USB mount & if results are the same, drop it in the recycle & get a new drive.

Comment: No, it was a regular seagate internal hdd. It worked great for quite a while. Can't really remember exactly, but for at least 5-6 years. And I used it heavily. It was the last internal hdd I've got for my PC. After that I started to get external ones. But thanks!

Comment: Probably a hardware problem. Few disks last beyond 5-6 years of heavy use.

Answer (score 0):

The logic board is probably going bad or the sata port on the drive is bad.  Esp. if you swapped the cables and it's not showing up in the bios, unfortunately I've had a couple of drives like that too.

If you have another pc you can test it on to see if it shows up, that would be a good start.

Other than below, you might want to look up the model and ensure that your bios sector detection didn't get hosed.  Older bios's let you set the sectors manually which might work if for some reason that data got corrupted, but you should still *see* the drive in the BIOS / OS.

There are two options if you need the data:

1. Buy a replacement logic board and warm up your soldering iron :)
2. You might be able to get data off of it by putting it in a freezer bag and letting it sit overnight or two in the freezer.  Get all the air out and be prepared to connect it and get as much data off as you can when you take it out as it will potentially ruin the drive due to moisture.  This is sort of a last ditch effort to preserve the data and assumes the drive is generally trashed.

The freezer trick will give you enough time to get data off before the chip overheats or the moisture causes long term damage, assuming the drive isn't super slow.

Comment: I think I can try this freezing option as a last resort. The Bios identifies the hdd (I'm confident the cables were working). It was disk management that couldn't really ID it. It showed a drive of 128gb instead. I tried to assign it thinking it was my ssd, but I would always get an I/O error.

Comment: So the bios displays the appropriate sector count / size?  If it's just diskmgmt.msc that can't see the proper size, definitely would want to run something on it like spinrite, and not the freezer method, to diagnose and try to fix it.  It might just be a corrupt MBR issue, but it's hard to diagnose.  Also might want to ensure shadowcopy service is enabled in windows.  If you have a linux system, try attaching it there and mounting w/ fat32 or ntfs filesystem.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Bios can tell the sector count/size, I can only say that when I had to reboot and choose a hdd or disk drive to boot it, it showed the hdd in question as an option.

Comment: I recently had a drive going bad on me, windows started choking, notified 'eminent failure' and was making that dreaded clicking noise. Pulled the disk from the system as windows was useless.

I'm planning on attempting a linux mount + dd and then I'll run spinrite on it. Hoping it's just some bad sectors. No time to work on it atm; I'll update as I make progress. BIOS sees the disk; windows was almost useless while the disk was attached. Only problem some disks were converted to GPT and spinrite doesn't support that.

I did confirm my efi bios doesn't let you set sector size.